# Is it better to use Math.signum(x) or Integer.compare(x, 0) in a switch statement?

Tags: java, int, switch-statement, compare, sign

Suppose I have an int x, and I want the code to do different things depending on the sign of x. If I use a switch statement, is it better (quicker) to use Integer.compare(x, 0) or Math.signum(x)?

```
switch (Integer.compare(x, 0)) {
case 1:
    // positive
    break;
case -1:
    // negative
    break;
case 0:
    // zero
    break;
}
```

vs.

```
switch (Math.signum(x)) {
case 1:
    // positive
    break;
case -1:
    // negative
    break;
case 0:
    // zero
    break;
}
```

Additionally, is there any performance difference between using `case 0:` and `default:`?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The contract of `Integer.compare` does _not_ guarantee that the answer is -1, 0 or 1.  Use this at your own peril.

Comment: Oh, is there any case when it would return something else? Or is it just subject to change in future versions of Java?

Comment: It may change in future versions.  The latest Java 8 version from Oracle has it return -1, 0 or 1.  I haven't checked other versions.  But as a general principle, you should _never_ assume that a method does something that its Javadoc doesn't say it does.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Also you're intention is the signum, so compare looks far fetched, even if it yields the same values (now).

Comment: If you're after speed, you might be best with something like `if (x > 0) { ... } else if (x < 0) { ... } else { ... }`

Comment: The problem with `Math.signum` is that it takes a floating point argument and returns a floating point result.  So 1) your switch needs a typecast to compile, and 2) the signum solution will *probably* be less efficient (unless the JIT compiler does some heroic optimization ...)

Comment: @StephenC if the input is known to be an integer, then `Integer.signum` should be used. The JDK source returns `(i >> 31) | (-i >>> 31)` which is pretty efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarizing all of the comments:

1. Using `Integer.compare` has the problem that the API contract doesn't specify that the result is -1, 0 or 1.  (That's what the current implementation returns, but it *could* change in a future version.)
2. `Math.signum` takes a `float` or `double` argument and returns a result of the same type.  So you need a typecasts (to `int`) in the `switch` statement.  Furthermore, the conversions and other things most likely make this less efficient.
3. `Integer.signum` is more efficient *and* it is specified to return -1, 0 or 1.
4. In this case `if (x > 0) { ... } else if (x < 0) { ... } else { ... }` is probably the most efficient.

If you really care, you could write a micro-benchmark to test the statements made above.

However beware of the pitfall of *premature optimization*; i.e. wasting time on hand optimizing methods where the performance *actually* makes minimal difference to overall application performance.

Comment: Oh, I didn't even know that `Integer.signum` existed, thanks! Answer accepted.